# what is the solution of following definite integration:

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{r=1}^n\frac1{x+r}\right)\left(\prod_{r=1}^n(x+r)\right)dx$$

I am not getting any good approach to solve this integral. any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks @Brian. its kind of little hard for me to upload the image properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea: note that the integrand is of the form

$$[(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)\cdots (x+n)] +[ (x+1)(x+3)(x+4)\cdots (x+n)] +[ (x+1)(x+2)(x+4)\cdots (x+n) ]+ \cdots [(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots (x+(n-1))].$$

Now, the derivative of each $x+r$ is $1$. See if you can employ the product rule to find an elementary integral.

Comment: can u please elaborate how can i employ chain rule on one of these products.

Comment: I realize after that I meant to say product rule. Can you find a function $f(x)$ whose derivative is the above by  the product rule?

Comment: got it. thanks a lot